# Update the date field to the date & time of the node being updated

Tags: 8, rules, datetime, tokens

I am sure that I am missing something very simple here, so I hope somebody can put me on the right track.

**Use Case:**

1. I have a simple content type **"Article"**
2. A date field of type: "Date and Time" is attached to this content
   type.
3. Using any of "Rules" or "Business rules" module, I need when
   updating a node of type "Article", **to set the value of the "date
   field" to be equal to the "date and time" of the node being
   updated.**

What is the right token that must be used ?

**So far:**

I have been trying for days with no success, I have tried to use the below token but yet no sucess:

- [node:changed:custom:D-M-Y-H:i:s]
- [node:changed:custom:D-M-Y H:i:s]
- [node:changed:custom:D/M/Y H:i:s]
- [node:changed:custom:DMYHis]

Any help PLEASE!!

**UPDATE #1:**

The real use case:

I am using the "Field Timer" module in my project which 
provides field formatters for core module Datetime to display timer or countdown as a formatter.

So every time the node is updated, I want to set the "date field" to the current "date and time" of the node being updated (+) 20 minutes.

For Example if the current date & time of the node being updated is: 31/12/2018 15:00:00 so I want to set the "date & time" field value to: 31/12/2018 15:20:00

So the countdown formatter will start from 20 minutes and down until 0 minute.

Thank you,

Comment: Are you able to provide a time value in Rules then? If so and if it takes PHP formats you can just enter “now +20 minutes”.

Answer (score 1):

Nodes already have a 'changed' property that would track this. Any reason why you don't want to use that? You can use `{{ node.getChangedTime() }}` in a Twig template for the raw value, or you can preprocess the node and take the changed value and format the date to your need into a new variable for the template. This way you don't need another field and Rules and reduce a lot of overhead.

Comment: I have a similar requirement and instead of opening a new question, maybe you could give a detailed example on how to add (+) let's say 30 minutes to a date field using a twig template as mentioned in you answer.